# How can I send a file from the Backend to download in the browser?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs3, multer

When I make the request with Postman or Thunder Client I can save the file, but when I try to do it from the browser I can't save it and the size is even larger than the original.

```
router.get('/files/download/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const file = await FileArea.findById(id);
    if (!file) {
      return res.status(404).send('File not found');
    }
    if (fs.existsSync (file.path)) {
      const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file.path); // read the file from the uploads folder with the path of the file in the database
      const readStream = new stream.PassThrough(); // create a stream to read the file
      readStream.end(fileContents); // end the stream
      res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + file.name); // set the name of the file to download with the name of the file in the database
      res.set('Content-Type', file.type);
      const fileToSend = readStream.pipe(res); // pipe the stream to the response
      return fileToSend;
    } else {
      return res.status(404).send('File not found');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');

  }
});
```

With this code from the frontend I try to put what is sent to a blob, which size is larger than the original file.
Example: The original file is 421KB and the Blob is 800KB

```
 async downloadFiles(id: string) {
      try {
        const { data } = await downloadFile(id);
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: data.type });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', data.name);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.remove();
```

Comment: If you check in the developer tools, what gets fetched? Also, can you share the code for downloadFile?